# How to add metadata to subtitle?

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, subtitles

I'm trying to add language metadata to existing external .ass subtitles, but it doesn't seem to work. I'm using `ffmpeg -i input.ass -map 0 "-metadata:s:s:0" "language=eng" "-metadata:s:s:0" "handler_name=English output.ass"` and it shows this

```
Input #0, ass, from 'input.ass':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Subtitle: ass
Output #0, ass, to 'output.ass':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Subtitle: ass (ssa)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : English
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 ssa
```

But in the end nothing changes. I used similar command a while ago to add metadata to subtitle streams inside mkv files, and it worked fine, so I don't get why it won't work with .ass directly.

Comment: The quotes in your command are completely off, especially the part containing the output filename. Check this: https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on a single subtitle file you don't have to use `map` option. It's really useful if you are working on files with multiple streams ie. videos with multiple audio and/or subtitle tracks but unnecessary for single stream files. For your use case this should suffice: `ffmpeg -i input.ass -metadata language="eng" output.ass`. Also in general watch how you use quotes in arguments, you put this two arguments into quotes `"handler_name=English output.ass"` and this whole thing gets interpreted as filename. Arguments starting with dash shouldn't be wrapped in quotes but if an argument accepts a parameter, quotes can be useful to prevent word splitting.